# How to print tamil letters in pdf when using mpdf?

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I'm using mpdf to convert pdf conversion from html.

I'm trying to print the following

```
$html = '<table  style = "width:300px;border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;">
            <tr style ="border: 1px solid black;">
                <td style = "border: 1px solid black;padding: 20px;text-align:center;">test</td>
                <td style = "border: 1px solid black;padding: 20px;text-align:center;">ராசி</td>
                <td style = "border: 1px solid black;padding: 20px;text-align:center;">ராசி</td>
                <td style = "border: 1px solid black;padding: 20px;text-align:center;">test</td>
            </tr>
</table>';
        $html = utf8_encode($html);
        $mpdf=new mPDF();
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $mpdf->Output();
```

I could be able to the document. But the tamil text is not able to print. It looks unreadable in pdf document.
What I want to do to get the tamil letters be printed? I tried encoding the html, but in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by including tamil font file **ind_ta_1_001.ttf** into 'ttfonts' folder and then to call it to pdf changed the code as below

```
    $mpdf=new mPDF('ta');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
```

It worked fine since mpdf supports for tamil language.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP documentation:

> utf8_encode — Encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8

What you have is already an utf-8 string. You don't need to convert it. Just remove the utf8_encode.

Comment: After removing the utf8_encode(), it results the same (Unreadable text!).

Comment: Make sure you have all the correct fonts installed. You need a font that can handle tamil characters.

Comment: I'm using the mpdf for the first time. I dont know how to add tamil font inside mpdf.

Answer (score 0):

This solution may help those who are looking for generating a report in pdf from php using fetched data from mysql database 100 % working.

```
<?php
    include('vendor/autoload.php');
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'ta-IN']); # for tamil country-india
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","matrimonial"); # my database
    $sql = "select * from rasi";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $html = "கல்யாணப்பரிசு திருமணத் தகவல் மையம் ";
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $rasi = $row['rasiname'];   
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($rasi);
    }

    $mpdf->Output();
?>
```